# Download file from Json object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am new to NodeJS. I am trying to download file from json object. I have json object that i received from Mongodb collection and I want to return json data as list in file.  I tried to download file from my local machine and that codes works. But not able to understand how should i return file from json object. Do i need to use Buffer for this. So far I have below test code.

```
    //Write Member File
exports.File  = function(req, res){
    var data =  getdata(function(err, members){
        //console.log(members);

//        var bf = buffer.Buffer(members, 'Binary').toString('base64');
//        console.log(bf.length);
        // I get bf.length as 4
        var file = 'C:/Docs/members.txt';
        var filename = path.basename(file);
        console.log(filename);
        var mimetype = 'text/plain';
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
        res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
        var fileStream =  fs.createReadStream(file);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This works with me.

```
var user = {"name":"azraq","country":"egypt"};
var json = JSON.stringify(user);
var filename = 'user.json';
var mimetype = 'application/json';
res.setHeader('Content-Type', mimetype);
res.setHeader('Content-disposition','attachment; filename='+filename);
res.send( json );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this.

```
function(req, res) {
    var jsonObj = getJSON();
    var data = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename= myFile.json');
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.write(data, function (err) {
        res.end();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to use Buffer for this.

No, a simple string that you [`.write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding) to the response will suffice.

```
exports.returnData = function(req, res){
    getdata(function(err, members){
        console.log(members); // I guess you have an object here, not a plain response
        var json = JSON.stringify(members); // so let's encode it

        var filename = 'result.json'; // or whatever
        var mimetype = 'application/json';

        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
        res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
        res.write(json);
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it return empty file and takes so long to download file. I can see data in console.log(members). But it doesn't come in file.

Comment: What does `console.log(json)` put?

Comment: console.log(members) put json array data.